# Как сделать ветвление в aiogram FSM в зависимости от ответа?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram

Есть код бота aoigram, FSM работает отлично, но вот появилась задача, сделать логику в зависимости от ответа пользователя.

```
class FSMHelp(StatesGroup):
    state1 = State()
    state2 = State()
    state3 = State()
    state4 = State()


async def cm_start(message: types.Message):
    await FSMHelp.state1.set()
    await message.reply('Выберите тип', reply_markup=but.buttons2)


async def load_state1(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    async with state.proxy() as data:
        data['state1'] = message.text
    await FSMHelp.next()
    await message.reply('Укажите документ', reply_markup=but.cancel_btn)


async def load_state2(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    async with state.proxy() as data:
        data ['state2'] = message.text
    await FSMHelp.next()
    await message.reply('Название организации', reply_markup=but.cancel_btn)


async def load_state3(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    async with state.proxy() as data:
        data['state3'] = message.text
    await FSMHelp.next()
    await message.reply('Контактное лицо', reply_markup=but.cancel_btn)


async def load_state4(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    async with state.proxy() as data:
        data ['state4'] = message.text
    await message.reply(answer, reply_markup=but.buttons)
    await state.finish()



def register_message_order(dp : Dispatcher):
    dp.register_message_handler(cm_start, regexp='.*заявка', state=None)
    dp.register_message_handler(load_state1, state=FSMHelp.state1)
    dp.register_message_handler(load_state2, state=FSMHelp.state2)
    dp.register_message_handler(load_state3, state=FSMHelp.state3)
    dp.register_message_handler(load_state4, state=FSMHelp.state4)
```

Как сделать, чтобы  при вводе в state1 "нет", пропускать ввод state2? А если было да, то выполнять всё...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не знаю, лучше это или нет, но я вообще перестал использовать `StatesGroup`-ы.

Для меня намного удобнее выбирать `state` через строку - `await state.set_state('name-of-state')`, после чего отлавливать по этой строке в хендлере - `dp.register_message_handler(handler, state='name-of-state'`.

Думаю, в вашем случае так будет сделать проще и удобнее.
Пример кода:

```
async def action_one(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):

    await state.set_state('next_state')
    ...


async def action_two(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):

    await state.finish()
    ...

dp.register_message_handler(action_one)
dp.register_message_handler(action_two, state='next_state')
```

При смене `state` через `set_state` данные стейта не пропадают.

Comment: а Вы не видели статьи на эту тему? В офф руководстве ничего про это нет, а примеров в интернете что то найти не могу....

Comment: Статей не видел, точнее не искал - учился на примерах по работе) Если вопросы есть - спрашивайте, постараюсь ответить

Comment: Я смотрю на Ваш пример  и мне вообще не понятно) В доках aiogram 3.х есть пример того что мне нужно, но я пишу на 2.х, а переписывать не хочется пока, да и там тоже не понятно) Я пытался сделать по аналогии, но ничего не получилось(

Comment: Если Вам не сложно, не могли бы Вы в моём коде выше это реализовать?

Comment: Мой пример как раз и сделан для 2.х)) Сейчас набросаю, секунду

Comment: Написал пример - https://pastebin.com/jWD5ksZ6 
Извиняйте, если сразу непонятно написал, в пейсте полная картина, думаю, разберетесь))

Comment: Спасибо большое за помощь!!!

Comment: Незачто, был рад помочь) Если решил вопрос, думаю, стоит пометить мой ответ как решение)

Answer (score 0):

Вроде разобрался, а может и нет, но всё равно работает как я хотел:

```
class FSMHelp(StatesGroup):
    state1 = State()
    state2 = State()
    state3 = State()
    state4 = State()


async def cm_start(message: types.Message):
    await FSMHelp.state1.set()
    await message.reply('Выберите тип', reply_markup=but.buttons2)


async def load_state1_yes(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    async with state.proxy() as data:
        data['state1'] = message.text
    await FSMHelp.next()
    await message.reply('Укажите документ', reply_markup=but.cancel_btn)


async def load_state1_no(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    async with state.proxy() as data:
        data['state1'] = message.text
    async with state.proxy() as data:
        data ['state2'] = 'нет'
    await message.reply('Название организации', reply_markup=but.cancel_btn)
    await state.set_state(FSMHelp.state3)


async def load_state2(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    async with state.proxy() as data:
        data ['state2'] = message.text
    await FSMHelp.next()
    await message.reply('Название организации', reply_markup=but.cancel_btn)


async def load_state3(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    async with state.proxy() as data:
        data['state3'] = message.text
    await FSMHelp.next()
    await message.reply('Контактное лицо', reply_markup=but.cancel_btn)


async def load_state4(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    async with state.proxy() as data:
        data ['state4'] = message.text
    await message.reply(answer, reply_markup=but.buttons)
    await state.finish()



def register_message_order(dp : Dispatcher):
    dp.register_message_handler(cm_start, regexp='.*заявка', state=None)
    dp.register_message_handler(load_state1_yes, (lambda message: message.text == 'Yes'), state=FSMHelp.state1)
    dp.register_message_handler(load_state1_no, (lambda message: message.text == 'No'), state=FSMHelp.state1)
    dp.register_message_handler(load_state2, state=FSMHelp.state2)
    dp.register_message_handler(load_state3, state=FSMHelp.state3)
    dp.register_message_handler(load_state4, state=FSMHelp.state4)
```

Может кто-то проверить насколько правильно я сделал?